# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'playerName' of undefined at eval

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to assign `response.data.Response.displayName` from my GET request to my playerName property, however, I am getting an error "`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'playerName' of undefined at eval`". I am successfully console logging `response.data.Reponse.displayName` so there is a displayName in it.

Why am I getting this error?

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      playerName: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('/User/GetBungieNetUserById/19964531/')
      .then(function(response) {
          this.playerName = response.data.Response.displayName
        console.log(response.data.Response.displayName)
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: use `(response) => { this.playerName = ...}`. With the `function` keyword you lose the original `this` context

Comment: use arrow function instead: `response=>{ this.playerName = /*..rest of code */}`

Comment: Hmmm, so it's mandatory to use arrow function in this case?

Comment: you could do `let that=this` before axios call, and inside the callback use `that` instead of `this`

Comment: @Bobimaru no you could do `function(response){/* code */}.bind(this)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other comments and answers are correct - using an arrow/lambda function instead of just `function` will work. But there's a nuance as to why.

Javascript's concept of `this` is well defined but not always what you'd expect from other languages. `this` can change within one scope block when you're executing from sub-functions of things like callbacks. In your case, the function in the `then` no longer understands `this` as the same as if you were running the same code directly inside `mounted()`.

You can bind functions, however, to (among other purposes) have a specific `this` attached that can't be changed. Arrow functions do this implicitly, and bind `this` to what `this` is in the context the arrow function is created. Therefore, this code:

```
axios.get('/User/GetBungieNetUserById/19964531/')
  .then((response) => {
      this.playerName = response.data.Response.displayName
    console.log(response.data.Response.displayName)
  });
```

understands `this` properly. It is (*roughly!*) equivalent to the following:

```
axios.get('/User/GetBungieNetUserById/19964531/')
  .then((function(response) {
      this.playerName = response.data.Response.displayName
    console.log(response.data.Response.displayName)
  }).bind(this));
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same thing but I get the error anyway. I use a function though.

Comment: It seems that my problem is that I didn't do in the "mounted()". I want to do it on a click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda function ( Arrow function ) to reach the code

```
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      playerName: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('/User/GetBungieNetUserById/19964531/')
      .then((response) => {
          self.playerName = response.data.Response.displayName
        console.log(response.data.Response.displayName)
      });
  }
}
```